# Run jQuery function when a certain number of checkboxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve the following with jQuery:

Select max 3 check boxes out of 20, when three check boxes are selected run jQuery function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm considering the example on the official documentation of Jquery:
http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

```
<script>
    function myFunction(){

    }

    function countChecked() {
      var n = $("input:checked").length;
      if(n==3){
         myFunction();
      }
    }

    $(":checkbox").click(countChecked);

</script>
```

Comment: how can i limit it though to three max at the same time?

Comment: It should be enough to let the countChecked function return false if n>3.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand correctly you want to run a function if three boxes are checked? To do that use

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){

if($(":checkbox:checked").length==3))
  //run function here
});
```